# what is meaning of subject to in the following sentence

Tags: usage

Hello there I m Sajid and I'm exceptionally confounded about the use of the phrase ***subject to***.

What is the significance of *subject to* in the following sentence?

> This was partially because in analyzing his data he used probability theory, an alien subject to most biologists of the time.

Comment: It's "an alien subject | to most biologists of the time" (not "an alien | subject to most biologists of the time"). To make it easier to see this, replace the word "to" with "for".

Comment: To most biologists of the time, probability theory was an alien subject." is an alternative phrasing that may make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

### Use of 'subject to' in this case

> This was partially because in analyzing his data he used probability theory, **an alien subject to** most biologists of the time.

Here, **to** can indeed be replaced by **for**, meaning that probability theory is a subject that wasn't well-known to the biologists. It is used as a **noun**, and is categorized as "alien".

### Use of 'subject to' in other cases

However, **subject to** can also be used in other cases, for example:

> This new set of rules is **subject to** last-minute changes.

Where it means that the rules **might** change, and where you could replace it with **prone to**.
Or:

> He is **subject to** his wife's will.

Where it conveys submission. In these, it's used as a *subject's attribute* and not as a noun any more.